# Rails + Amazon s3 + jquery file upload : upload progress bar not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am currently using the railscasts jquery file upload tutorial's progress bar code (http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload) and it was working fine before adding Amazon S3. I'm using only the basic version of jquery file upload without the UI.

The bar shows up but it's just an empty grey bar (though the pics upload completely). Is there a reason behind this? And is there another way to do this (so that it works)?

photos/new.html.erb

```
<div class="clearfix">

<div class="uploadreminder">
    Upload multiple pictures at once or drag them directly to the browser!
</div>
<%= form_for([@user, @album, @photo], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

<%= f.file_field :avatar, multiple: true, name: "photo[avatar]" %>

<% end %>

<div class="finisheduploading">
    <%= link_to "Back to album", user_album_path(@user, @album) %>
</div>



<div id="pics">
    <%= render :partial => "photo", :collection => @photos %>
</div>


    #this is the part that is supposed to make the progress bar
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<div class="upload">
  {%=o.name%}
  <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
</div>
</script>
</div>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require fancybox
//= require 'js/bootstrap.js'
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
  $("a.fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();


});
```

photos.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
$('#new_photo').fileupload
  dataType: "script"
  add: (e, data) ->
    types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
    file = data.files[0]
    if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
      data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
      $('#new_photo').append(data.context)
      data.submit()
    else
      alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")
  progress: (e, data) ->
    if data.context
      progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
      data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

my complete code is here: https://github.com/EdmundMai/pholderbeta/blob/master/app/views/photos/new.html.erb

Answer (score 4):

if it can help, I wrote a tutorial about that : http://pjambet.github.com/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/ , and there's a live demo : http://direct-upload.herokuapp.com/photos Code is hosted on github : https://github.com/pjambet/direct-upload

Comment: Hello Pjam, I just went through your tutorial and demo, but it doesnt let me upload multiple files at once does it?

Comment: Hi, on my tutorial I didn't use the multiple option. But from what I can remember, just adding `multiple` to the file input will allow you to upload more than one file. Then you have a little more work to do to handle those files, but you should be able to do it. Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 2):

Ryan missed one thing to tell that you have to add a style in your css file if you look on his code you will find following style in his painting.css file.

```
.upload .progress .bar {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3EC144;
  height: 100%;
}
```